# Voiced "th" in "thank you"?

Tags: english, phonology, dental-fricative

I have a friend, a native English speaker from Boston, MA, USA (I believe he is mostly Irish American), who is absolutely adamant that the first sound in "thank you" is voiced, rather than voiceless. Moreover, one of his college English professors (also a native English speaker, but not sure where from) agrees.

My friend acknowledges that all the dictionaries seem to say that the sound is voiceless; moreover, I was able to produce numerous examples from YouTube where a native speaker clearly uses the voiceless "th" (e.g., [Matthew McConaughey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wD2cVhC-63I#t=1m23s) and
[Viola Davis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb5dS_Ei1QE#t=1m45s)).

And still he---and his professor---insist that, in their daily lives, they have never heard the "th" in "thank you" pronounced as anything other than voiced.

My question is: is the voiced "th" in "thank you" something that is well-known and documented as a regional variant? Or is there something else going on here?

(I also posed this question on the Linguist List, [here](http://askaling.linguistlist.org/question/734/voiced-th-in-thank-you/)... no answers yet.)

**Update:**

1. Alex B. pointed out that there indeed exists some published research: The Survey of English Dialects (Orton et al. 1962-71) recorded "a number of instances of the voicing of all four fricatives in word-initial (Anlaut) position in the South and the South-West Midlands" (Fisiak 1988); see [Voitl 1988](http://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110848137/9783110848137.565/9783110848137.565.xml?format=EBOK) (also [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ptAb7J1DUZAC&lpg=PA565&ots=A9kr9JyWxi&dq=%22The%20history%20of%20voicing%20of%20initial%20fricatives%20in%20Southern%20England%22&pg=PA565#v=onepage&q=%22The%20history%20of%20voicing%20of%20initial%20fricatives%20in%20Southern%20England%22&f=false)). Related research includes that by Martyn Wakelin, esp. Wakelin and Barry (1968).
2. From the comments by musicallinguist, it seems that sometimes even among siblings raised in the same household there can be a difference in the voicing of the initial "th," which persists into adulthood.
3. I have discovered that, several months prior to my original posting of the present question, essentially [the same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236848/pronunciation-of-thank-using-%C3%B0-voiced-th-instead-of-%CE%B8-unvoiced-th/) had been posted to the English stackexchange. The original asker was motivated by the observation described in 2. above, in her own family (though it is unclear what are the ages of her siblings who pronounce the "th" as voiced). One contributor there stated that the voiced "th" in "thank" can be found "[i]n parts of New England," but, as of yet, no one has provided published references for this.

In light of this, let me refine my question a bit.

A. Is there any published research on the situations where even among native speakers who were born and raised (and live) in the same area, or even the same household, there are some who pronounce the "th" as voiceless, and some who pronounce it as voiced? Are those with the minority pronunciation usually aware that they are in the minority, or are they usually not really aware of it?

B. Also helpful would be examples of (research on) other kinds of within-group linguistic differences---those that are in some relevant sense 'similar' to the difference in the voicing. As far as what exactly should count as 'similar,' well, that is itself kind of a part of the question. Here is one proposal for what it may mean: the differences in some linguistic feature such that 1. one would *not expect* this feature to vary within such a (linguistically close) group of people; 2. the group members exhibiting this feature are clearly in the minority, but, at the same time, they are also clearly a *group* and not just a couple of isolated cases; 3. there is no relevant pathology (e.g. impaired hearing or speech processing or speech production) that could explain the existence of the subgroup with the minority feature.

C. Further references on regional variation with respect to the voicing of the initial "th" would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen real data on this, but to my ears (I'm from the tri-state area in the US) the voiced version sounds very weird.  That said, my own brother has it in his dialect!  I've also discussed this with another linguist who has the voiceless variant like me, and out of her three children one of them has the voiced variant. If there are regional tendencies, they can't be the only explanation given these two data points!

Comment: I would ask for objective acoustic evidence to support the contention. While you are asking, get examples of other words with expected initial [θ] vs. [ð], esp. "this'll" vs. "thistle". Get data from the professor as well.

Comment: So does your friend say it with the voiced version? And surely if you produce the voiceless version (which is the only version I, a native speaker of Australian English, have ever heard in that word) then he's heard at least one person?

Comment: @musicallinguist That's really unexpected...!  Is your brother aware that his variant is different than yours, and different from most other people's?

Comment: @user6726 Objective acoustic evidence might be a tall order... this is why I was hoping someone might know of a research that had already been done. But I can certainly try to find out if there are any other "th" sounds my friend pronounces differently from what is stated in dictionaries.

Comment: @gaston-Ümlaut  I am not a native English speaker, so perhaps he thought I am simply saying it wrong... Or simply wasn't paying attention, until we started discussing it.

Comment: My brother might have forgotten by now, but I used to tease him about it when we were younger.  My linguist colleague also pointed it out to her daughter many times.

Comment: @musicallinguist But your brother still persists in using the voiced version? And does he agree that most other people use the voiceless one?

Comment: It's not the sort of thing he pays a lot of attention to.  Conventional wisdom in our family is that I got our mom's "language genes" and my brother inherited our dad's difficulties with language.

Comment: Voted to protect this question as it attracts low-quality answers from personal experience.

Comment: I know of at least one youtuber who uses eth-not-thorn in "thanks" (Alex from Technology Connections), and it always throws me off.

Comment: “he---and his professor---insist that, in their daily lives, they have never heard the "th" in "thank you" pronounced as anything other than voiced” — Well, this bit is at least irrefutably false. Even if voicing the initial fricative is fairly common where they live, it is by no means ubiquitous, and given the number of people we hear utter the words ‘thank you’ throughout our lives, there is absolutely zero chance that either of them has never heard it pronounced the far more common way, with a voiceless fricative.

Answer (score 4):

Both my brother and I substitute a voiced dental fricative (ð) at the beginning of words where most American English speakers would have a voiceless dental fricative (θ).  This is often accompanied by a change to the vowel.

Thus "thanks" (θænks) becomes "thenks" (ðɛnks).

We are from northeastern Ohio if that is of any use to you.  I have not been able to find an official name for this variation.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thank said it is /θæŋk/. IIRC, English doesn't have /c/ sound. It sounds nearly the same with /tʃ/ in cheese

Comment: @Mike Thanks, that is very interesting... Is it your impression that this is typical for the people who grew up in the area? For instance, do most of the people you went to grade school with also pronounce these words like you and your brother do?

Comment: @Danh Yes, as mentioned in the original question, all the dictionaries say that the "th" in "thanks" is voiceless. However, as evident from the discussion here, there is a subgroup of native speakers who use the voiced sound. My main question, in fact, is whether there is any actual  published research on the topic. Having said that, the anecdotal evidence presented above is certainly interesting... 
Also, I'm a bit confused by your comment on the /c/ sound... Could you explain a bit why you are mentioning it?

Comment: @linguisticturn I just want to correct the IPA symbols in Mike's answer. Because it's /k/ sound not /c/ sound. /c/ sound is completely difference from /k/

Comment: @linguisticturn as a matter of fact, yes, this phenomenon has been described in dialectal research (Awedik 1992 confirms this), see e.g Voitl 1988 http://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110848137/9783110848137.565/9783110848137.565.xml?format=EBOK and also Fisiak 1988, who mentions The Survey of English Dialects (Orton et al.1962-71) recording "a number of instances of the voicing of all four fricatives in word-initial (Anlaut) position in the South and the South-West Midlands"; see research by Martyn Wakelin, esp. Wakelin and Barry (1968).

Comment: @ Alex-B Thank you! I'll update the original question with this information.

Comment: I'll have to look into this, but my own impression is that voiced 'thank you' is not at all a rare variant.

Answer (score 2):

My own personal experience (US English) has been only hearing "thanks" said with voiced dental fricative from young adult speakers less than 25 years of age (2010-2015 time range). It doesn't seem to be uniform within that age group, and is usually only apparent when the word "thanks" or "thank" is the first word in the sentence. The pronunciation variant doesn't seem to extend to conventionally voiceless dental fricatives like "thought" or "thin". Just my own anecdotal observations. I don't have any hard data to present about it, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! Where in the US, if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: My impressions are similar (in northern CA).

Answer (score 0):

One of the pastors at our church in suburban Chicago says "thank" and "thanks" with a voiced dental fricative. I had never heard it before and it took me a while to figure out why it sounded so strange.  I found this thread when I decided to research if it was a regional dialect.  He grew up in Kalamazoo, MI.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. ONce you have gained a few points of reputation here, you can comment everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up around Boston, Ma and I would always pronounce the th in thanks and thank you as voiced never voiceless.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! An anecdotal evidence can't serve an answer in our format. It could be only a part that confirms author's personal point, but the main core of the answer should be based on scientific approach, backed with credible references and academic works. Otherwise, think what happens if every user posted an answer about they *they* pronounce `/th/` in their families.